# Is it possible to trigger an Airflow 2 dag from an Airflow 1 dag, and viceversa?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

We are doing a migration between new and old Airflow and we were trying to implement a trigger from Airflow1 to Airflow2(and vice-versa), is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since running Airflow 1 code in an Airflow 2 instance will likely result in errors, I assume you intend to have two Airflow instances? One running Airflow 1, and one running Airflow 2, where the Airflow 2 DAGs trigger Airflow 1 DAGs?

To trigger a DAG externally, such as another Airflow instance, you can use the REST API or CLI to trigger DAGs:

CLI ([docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#trigger)):

```sh
airflow dags trigger DAG_ID
# For example:
airflow dags trigger mydag-airflow1
```

REST API ([docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_dag_run)):

```sh
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dags/mydag-airflow1/dagRuns
```

Couple of things to note:

- REST API and CLI were rewritten in Airflow 2. If you intend to trigger from Airflow 1 to 2, you must look up the respective command for the old REST API/CLI.
- Maintaining codebases for different versions can quickly become messy. I'd advise to stick to one Airflow version.

Comment: Thanks a lot! We will have two instances only during the migration, then we will stick with Airflow2